# keeping in-line record of previous unique value -- dplyr to data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to convert a dplyr function I have to data.table and finding it hard to  achieve parity. Any help much appreciated!

**data**

```r
DT = data.table(
  "brk" = 1L,
  "est" = c(900, 900, 1000, 1000, 1100),
  "t" = c(0, 12, 15, 22, 30)
)
```

**desired outcome**

```r
Desired_DT = data.table(
  "brk" = 1L,
  "est" = c(900, 900, 1000, 1000, 1100),
  "t" = c(0, 12, 15, 22, 30),
  "prev_est" = c(NA, NA , 900, 900, 1000),
  "prev_est_age" = c(NA, NA, 15, 22, 15)
)
```

**one possible dplyr way**

```r
DT %>% 
  left_join(
    DT %>% 
      group_by(est) %>% 
      slice(1) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(
        prev_est = lag(n = 1L, est),
        prev_t = lag(n = 1L, t)
      )
  ) %>% tidyr::fill(.data$prev_est, .data$prev_t) %>% 
  mutate(prev_est_age = t - prev_t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that does similar syntax as in the tidyverse

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
# get the first row, grouped by 'est', create two lag columns of 'est', t'
dt1 <- DT[, head(.SD, 1), est][, c("prev_est", "prev_t") := 
        shift(.SD), .SDcols = c('est', 't')][] 
# do a join on 'brk', 'est', 't', do the `fill` the `na.locf0` from `zoo`
# and lastly create the column 'prev_est_age' as the difference of t, prev_t
dt1[DT, on = .(brk, est, t)][, c("prev_est", "prev_t") := lapply(.SD, 
  zoo::na.locf0), .SDcols = c("prev_est", "prev_t")][,
      prev_est_age := t - prev_t][]
```

---

We can make use of rolling join as well

```
dt1 <- unique(DT, by = 'est')[,  paste0("prev_", names(DT)[2:3]) := 
           shift(.SD), .SDcols = est:t][]
out <- dt1[DT, on = .(brk, est, t), roll = Inf][, 
                prev_est_age := t - prev_t][, prev_t := NULL][]
identical(Desired_DT, out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That looks pretty good, thanks for the quick reply! 

I'm a bit worried about using zoo though as I'm going to apply this function to a large dataset. Is there no data.table native way of achieving the roll-forward?

Comment: thanks that's pretty good! Another little twists here.. I've just realised that if est repeats at any point, this solution will fall flat.. any idea of how to account for this?

Comment: I prepared the data differently and solved the above issue. Still used the logic you provided so thanks for that! I essentially created cumsum on diff := ifelse((est - shift(est)) != 0,1,0) and grouped on it.

Comment: @codesaurus  Good to know that you have solved the issue